# Call a Craft variable inside array

Tags: variable, array

I'm currently trying to call variables called `{{entry.title}}`, `{{entry.latitude}}` and so on in an array.

This is what it looks like:

```
{% set markerArray = [] %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('xSpots') %}
    {% set tempMarkerArray = [
    {'name':'{{entry.title}}','url':'{{entry.Url}}','lat':'{{entry.latitude}}','lng':'{{entry.longitude}}'}
    ] %}
    {% set markerArray = markerArray|merge(tempMarkerArray) %}
{% endfor %}
```

When calling `{{markerArray[0].name}}` afterwards I am expecting it to return the proper title of the entry in Craft, instead it only returns "{{entry.title}}", as if the variable is not properly recognized while filling the array.

Any help? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To output variables inside an array like that you'd simply omit the twig braces.. at the moment the `'` are telling whatever is inside them to output as a string.

UPDATE: try adding parentheses around each variables like so

```
{'name':(entry.title),'url':(entry.Url),'lat':(entry.latitude),'lng':(entry.longitude)} ] %}
```

Comment: I already tried that, however when removing the `'` craft throws an error at me:

Comment: `'`A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".`'`

Comment: That totally worked! Thank you for the super fast answer! :)